# ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Exception

Tags: java, exception

```
public class Repetition {
  public static void main (String[]a){
    int[] x;
    x = new int[10];
    int i;
    int n=0;
      for (i=0;i<x.length;i++){
        n++;
        x[i]=n;
        System.out.print(x[i] + " ");
      }
    i=0;
    while (x[i]<x[10]){
      System.out.println(x[i]);
      i++;
   }
}
```

After running the program, it displays this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
at Repetition.main(Repetition.java:14)
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 Java Result: 1
```

Actually, I'm still a newbie in this language. I'm trying to create a program that will assign values into arrays of 10 and displays them and displays again starting from the first array.

I want the output to be like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` means you tried to use an index into an array, and that index doesn't exist. For example, if the last valid index in an array is 9 and you use 10 you'll get this error.

This line of code is the problem (the error message tells you the line number):

```
while (x[i]<x[10]){
```

`x` is an array of length 10, which means it has indices which go from 0 (zero) to 9. `x[10]` doesn't exist so you get the error.